# Lag on loading LZMA compressed file in Unity

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, unity-game-engine, lzma

I have written simple terrain loading in Unity 3D. The terrain is compressed with this tool: https://bitbucket.org/Agent_007/lzma-unity/overview.
I am using this script, that I written:

```
void loadAfterFirst() {
        byte[] terrainBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(streamingAssetsPathVar, "terrain/" + Chunk + ".terrain"));
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        //FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "terrain/" + Chunk + ".terrain"), FileMode.Open);
        LoadingSavingClass myClass = bf.Deserialize(new MemoryStream(LZMAtools.DecompressLZMAByteArrayToByteArray(terrainBytes))) as LoadingSavingClass;

        terrain = myClass.terrain;
}
```

but when I load it start this function while testing, whole game freeze and I have to wait until it loads. I put this function into new thread and it didn't helped. If you want to see how I written the thread, it looks this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(loadAfterFirst));
t.Start();    // Starts new thread
```

Comment: *"I put this function into new thread and it didn't work.*" Please explain eat you mean by that. What happens when you call it from another Thread? In order to save time, it would be good to post how `terrain` is declared and show what the `LoadingSavingClass` class looks like. That's very important here since you are using Thread.

Comment: Sorry ,it worked, I meaned, it didn't helped.

Comment: The lag is still there? That's what you mean? See what I said you should do in my first comment. I can't help  you without that

Comment: Yes, the lag is still there!

Comment: See what I said you should do in my first comment. I can't help you without that

Comment: I declare it globaly this like public `char[,,] terrain;` and the class looks: `[Serializable]
public class LoadingSavingClass
{
    public char[,,] terrain = new char[128, 32, 128];
}`

Comment: When people ask you more about code, edit it to your question not to the comment section. I don't see anything wrong with that code and it should work. /at this moment it is worth posting the complete code including how you are calling the function that starts the Thread.

Comment: Code works, but my question is how to optimize it, it allways get to lag on calling this thread so problem is with it, I don't mind loading time, I justwant to not lag on calling it.